# SD card left with barely any space after formatting it to ExFAT

Tags: disk-utility, disk-format, sd-card, fat32, exfat

I'm currently trying to jailbreak my Wii with an SD card and am using a MacBook Pro (El Capitan) to format the card to ExFat. The card is 32 gigs, but is reduced down to a mere 30 MBs after formatting to ExFAT via Disk Utility. I need to put one 40 MB file and one 2 MB file in the card, but it isn't letting me. FAT32 isn't working either. [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008IA1R56) is the link to the specific SD card I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

That card is **32 MB** not **32 GB** - unfortunately you misread the capacity by a factor of 1000

[image]